# Payfort Signature mismatch

Tags: java, sha256, payfort

I have this request body to generate report:

```
{
    "from_date":"2020-06-17T00:00:01+03:00",
    "to_date":"2020-06-18T10:59:59+03:00",
    "signature":"df4c2bbbd5dd044036e11f26845a170b93249fd657339bf88b59b6340e2f****",
    "merchant_identifier":"gGRRR***",
    "merchant_reference":"1592472727964",
    "columns":["amount","card_number"],
    "query_command":"GENERATE_REPORT",
    "access_code":"VYqRIJEhOHNFgDMbu***"
}
```

And I have my signature before signing as :

```
MYPASSaccess_code=VYqRIJEhOHNFgDMbu***columns=[amount,card_number]from_date=2020-06-17T00:00:01+03:00merchant_identifier=gGRRR***merchant_reference=1592472727964query_command=GENERATE_REPORTto_date=2020-06-18T10:59:59+03:00MYPASS
```

So its Hash256  = `df4c2bbbd5dd044036e11f26845a170b93249fd657339bf88b59b6340e2f****`

But the hash I have received in the response is:

```
1b3d301ff248ec0848eeb1376f4b4344e648cba60f18c63dcc9e939d6c83****
```

What am I making wrong? May be something related to **date**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far: I found in the documentation an [important note](https://docs.payfort.com/pdf/PAYFORT_Merchant_Integration_Guide_V_8.8.pdf):

> NOTE!
>
>  In the columns parameter; you should:
>
> 1. Open brackets.
> 2. **Put a “comma” then a “space” between the columns value**.
>
> Example: columns=[acquirer_name, authorization_code, amount, bin_number]
>
>  In
> the filters parameter; you should:
>
> 1. Open brackets.
> 2. Then open a curly brackets.
> 3. Write the “key”
> 4. Put a “comma” then a “space.
> 5. Write the “value” of the key.

Answer (score 0):

payfort document talk about generate your signature in following link you can see it

[signature document](https://paymentservices-reference.payfort.com/docs/api/build/index.html#signature)